# Momentum conservation in special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum, conservation-laws

In my textbook Kleppner, this question is given in the problem bank.

[image]

We define momentum 4-vector in Kleppner as:

```
momentum-4-vector = (px, py, pz, (gamma * i * rest_mass * c))
```

i makes it imaginary.
Gamma is the Lorentz constant.
c is the speed of light.

Now, this is the solution that I found online. (It might have an error in it as I don't know whether it is the official solution or not.)

[image]

Now, I understand that we have changed the frame of reference in the question right after the collision. We go to the center-of-mass frame. This gives us an advantage that the first 3 components of the momentum 4-vector are 0 after collision, as the net momentum in the center-of-mass frame is always zero. (until an external force is applied). We can still equate the norms of the 4-vectors as the change of frames will just do a rotation, that's it.

**MY DOUBT** :

In the solution, we haven't multiplied by gamma.
Why is it and what can be the suitable gamma in this case?

I would really appreciate answers without the use of inner products of 4-vectors and all the advanced stuff about 4-vectors as, it's not taught in my course and textbook (Kleppner).

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem.

Please don't post screenshots of text. It breaks search functionality, and it doesn't work for blind users.

Comment: *I would really appreciate answers without the use of inner products of 4-vectors and all the advanced stuff about 4-vectors as, it's not taught in my course and textbook (Kleppner).* Kleppner does have a treatment of 4-vectors.

Comment: Please credit the author of the solution. Please don't cut and paste on the internet without crediting the author. It's rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because they are at rest so $\gamma=1$.

The idea behind calculating threshold energy is to assume that all products are produced at rest in the COM frame. This way you get the energy just enough to produce them.

Consider a process in lab frame
$$A+B \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}C_i $$

To calculate the threshold energy, we do the following:

1. Assume the product system was to be produced at rest. This way we wouldn't be  supplying any energy for the momentum of the system - only its rest energy. This however isn't true since the reactant system may have some momentum. So we transition to the COM frame, do our calculations there and transition back.
2. However this isn't enough to calculate the bare minimum threshold. This is because it may be that in the COM frame, the COM mass isn't the sum of the individual rest masses. Its possible that each individual product has some momentum though the net is zero. To get the threshold we assume that they don't.

Comment: Thank you LINEAGE for the quick reply. Can you just confirm that I am correct in saying this? :  "If we have any Kinetic energy in the C.O.M. frame, we can reduce it with the help of internal forces. This will also reduce the Kinetic energy in laboratory frame. We cannot however go further below this situation of ZERO K.E. in C.O.M. frame with the use of just Internal Forces. To get the threshold value, we assume that we are in this lucky situation."

Comment: Thats one way to understand it but better not bring up any internal forces --there are no internal forces amongst products and nobody is using them to reduce any kinetic energy. Its not just internal forces--there is absolutely no mechanism by which you can go below the sum of rest energies.

Comment: Its just that for threshold this would be the min energy config to look for. On the other hand if there were some internal forces in the products, the threshold will be higher since, if the force is conservative, energy for the field config will also need to be supplied.  On the other hand, that subset of products with internal forces would rather be considered as one big product rather than individual products interacting.

Comment: In high energy collisions we treat the products as if they are infinitely far away from each other--all interaction occur only at the interaction vertex.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your answer!